# Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for org.camunda.bpm.webapp:camunda-webapp:[unknown-version]

Tags: eclipse, maven, github, camunda

I have the following problem. I downloaded the zip file with camunda webapp project and imported it to eclipse. Now I'm trying to compile it but it doesn't work for me.
below is the path for pom.xml file
https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-webapp/blob/a80f58535f6675c04f16d31d99002b7f7c8850d1/pom.xml

When I try to execute maven clean command, the command line says:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Downloading: http://10.232.196.180:8081/repository/mavenRepo/org/camunda/bpm/camunda-database-settings/7.5.7-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloading: http://10.232.196.180:8081/repository/mavenRepo/org/camunda/bpm/camunda-database-settings/7.5.7-SNAPSHOT/camunda-database-settings-7.5.7-SNAPSHOT.pom
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for org.camunda.bpm.webapp:camunda-webapp:[unknown-version]: Could not transfer artifact org.camunda.bpm:camunda-database-settings:pom:7.5.7-SNAPSHOT from/to nexus (http://10.232.196.180:8081/repository/mavenRepo/): Failed to transfer http://10.232.196.180:8081/repository/mavenRepo/org/camunda/bpm/camunda-database-settings/7.5.7-SNAPSHOT/camunda-database-settings-7.5.7-SNAPSHOT.pom. Error code 400, Bad Request and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 6, column 11
 @ 
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project org.camunda.bpm.webapp:camunda-webapp:[unknown-version] (D:\camunda\projects\camunda-bpm-webapp-7.5.0\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for org.camunda.bpm.webapp:camunda-webapp:[unknown-version]: Could not transfer artifact org.camunda.bpm:camunda-database-settings:pom:7.5.7-SNAPSHOT from/to nexus (http://10.232.196.180:8081/repository/mavenRepo/): Failed to transfer http://10.232.196.180:8081/repository/mavenRepo/org/camunda/bpm/camunda-database-settings/7.5.7-SNAPSHOT/camunda-database-settings-7.5.7-SNAPSHOT.pom. Error code 400, Bad Request and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 6, column 11 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

Answer (score 1):

The SNAPTSHOTS only available over the Camunda nexus repository.
Add the repository to your pom.xml

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>camunda-bpm</id>
    <repositories>
      <repository>
        <id>camunda-bpm-nexus</id>
        <name>camunda-bpm-nexus</name>
        <releases>
          <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
          <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <url>https://app.camunda.com/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
      </repository>
    </repositories>
  </profile>
</profiles>
<activeProfiles>
  <activeProfile>camunda-bpm</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
```

Source: https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-platform#building-camunda-bpm-platform